# Loading web pages in webview in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

i have a link for example,"http://google.com" , i need to load the web page in to my app either in web view or some other View, but not in default Browser of android , whether it is possible or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to **load URL in webview within the application**. If i am not wrong, then you can have:

```
WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    /* On Android 1.1 shouldOverrideUrlLoading() will be called every time the user clicks a link,
     * but on Android 1.5 it will be called for every page load, even if it was caused by calling loadUrl()! */
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        /* intercept all page load attempts and load yahoo.com instead */
        String myAlternativeURL = "http://yahoo.com";
        if (!url.equals(myAlternativeURL)) {
            view.loadUrl(myAlternativeURL);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});

browser.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

And In general, you can also use **`webview.loadURL(URL)`** method to load URL in webview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using WebView,
use the API , webview.loadUrl(your_url);
give internet access permission in Android Manifest file.

Check here,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

check e.g. with loadUrl();

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html), and launch the url within that.

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebC());
        webview.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    }

    public class WebC extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
    ... etc.
```

And in your layout xml,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```