# Issuing a token to an android app

Tags: android, authentication, token

I am developing an android app where I have shown a login page to my website into a `WebView`. Now, after the user successfully logs into your web site, the site will need to redirect the user over to a page which generates a token ("token page"). This token is then passed to the mobile application for authentication.

I am not sure on how to go ahead with this.Can anyone provide me with a tutorial or example on how to achieve this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I think you have to track url changes .

Comment: @keshav how can I do that?

Comment: Use WebViewClient http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496664/loading-web-pages-in-webview-in-android http://javatechig.com/android/android-webview-example

Comment: @keshav I have already loaded a site into my `WebView` Its a login page. Lets say `www.yahoo.com` . I enter my userId and password. I want the page to authenticate it but not redirect to the next page like it would in a normal browser. I want to load another page after the user enters his credentials

Comment: @keshav Your links point to how to use a WebView and load a certain url . Doesnt show how to track the urls

Comment: In shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, u are getting current url means after change in url, use that .